# Slicing converts UserList to list

Tags: python, collections

While implementing a custom list (via `UserList`) I noticed that all slicing operations return a type of `list` not of the derived class type.  This creates an issue that, after slicing, none of the added functionality is available in the object.  Here is a quick test program to demonstrate the issue, just note the the actual code is more complicated.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from collections import UserList

class myList(UserList):
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        super().__init__(data)
    def setFunc(self, data):
        self.data.extend(data)
    def getFunc(self):
        return self.data

l1 = myList()
l1.setFunc([1,2,3,4])
print(type(l1))
l2 = l1[:3]
print(type(l2))
print(l2.getFunc())

<class '__main__.myList'>
<class 'list'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 17, in <module>
    print(l2.getFunc())
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'getFunc'
```

I can overcome this issue by "casting" the `list` with `l2 = myList(l1[:3])` but it seems like the right solution would be to implement this functionality directly in `myList`.

I'm not certain the correct/most-elegant way to do this.  I suspect putting a cast in `__getitem__` would work.  Is that the best way or is there a more direct change to the slicing that would be preferred?  Also, what other methods should I override in order to assure all operations return a `myList` not a `list`?

Answer (score 1):

### My Answer

This is a bug in Python 3.6 and fixed in 3.7:

- ref: https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/13203/files

Currently, `Python 3.7-` is `EOL`, please use `Python 3.8+`.

---

```
$ python3.6 _.py

<class '__main__.myList'>
<class 'list'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../_.py", line 20, in <module>
    print(l2.getFunc())
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'getFunc'
```

```
python3.7 _.py                                   
<class '__main__.myList'>
<class '__main__.myList'>
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this isn't the default behavior in `UserList` but implementing the following in the derived class seems to fix the issue.

```
def __getitem__(self, i):
    new_data = self.data[i]
    if type(new_data) == list:
        return self.__class__(new_data)
    else:
        return new_data
```

The parameter `i` for `__getitem__` apparently can be either a `slice` object or an integer so `new_data` will either be a `list` or a single element.  If it's a `list` put it in the `myList` container and return.  Otherwise, if it's a single element, just pass that back.

Comment: It looks like it has been fixed in Python 3.8, `UserList([0,1,2,3])[0:2].__class__` now returns `UserList`

Comment: Yes it's been incorporated in later versions of python that slicing a UserList initializes a new UserList of the same type assigning it only the subset of the data indicated in the requested slice. So slicing a UserList returns a UserList.

Comment: This is bad. What if the elements *are* `list`s? Then you incorrectly convert them. I'd say you'd better check whether `i` is a `slice`.

Answer (score 0):

@bivouac0's answer would incorrectly convert an item that is a list itself to a `UserList` instance when `i` is not a slice by testing whether the type of what's returned by `self.data[i]` is a `list`.

It also incurs an unnecessary overhead by making a redundant copy of the sliced list `self.data[i]` when constructing a new `UserList` with `self.__class__(new_data)`, which always creates a new list from the given iterable.

To fix the former issue, one can test whether `i` is a slice instead to decide if `self.data[i]` should be converted to a `UserList`.

And to avoid making a redundant copy of the sliced list when constructing a new `UserList`, one can skip the original `__init__` method by creating a new instance with the `__new__` method instead and then assigning the sliced list as the `data` attribute of the new instance directly without making another copy:

```
from collections import UserList

class List(UserList):
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        new_data = self.data[i]
        if isinstance(i, slice):
            instance = super().__new__(self.__class__)
            instance.data = new_data
            return instance
        return new_data
```